# Adding Donchian Channel and Bollinger Bands together

Tags: pine-script

I am trying to add Donchian Channel and Bollinger Bands together. Though my script is not showing any error, but it's neither plotting the Bollinger Bands on chart. I think the problem lies in input declaration line for Bollinger Bands. Instead of using 20 Period SMA it's taking input from 20 Period ATR same as Dochian Channel. My code is as follows -

```
//@version=5
indicator(title="Donchian Channels", shorttitle="DC", overlay=true, timeframe="", timeframe_gaps=true)
length = input.int(20, minval=1)
lower = ta.lowest(length)
upper = ta.highest(length)
basis = math.avg(upper, lower)
plot(basis, "Basis", color=#FF6D00)
u = plot(upper, "Upper", color=#2962FF)
l = plot(lower, "Lower", color=#2962FF)
fill(u, l, color=color.rgb(33, 150, 243, 95), title="Background")

///BB
length = input.int(20, minval=1)
src = input(close, title="Source")
mult = input.float(2.0, minval=0.001, maxval=50, title="StdDev")
basis = ta.sma(src, length)
dev = mult * ta.stdev(src, length)
upper_bb = basis + dev
lower_bb = basis - dev
offset = input.int(0, "Offset", minval = -500, maxval = 500)
plot_bb(basis, "Basis", color=#FF6D00, offset = offset)
p1 = plot(upper, "Upper", color=#2962FF, offset = offset)
p2 = plot(lower, "Lower", color=#2962FF, offset = offset)
fill_bb(p1, p2, title = "Background", color=color.rgb(33, 150, 243, 95))
```

Please help me to fix this issue. Thanks & regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script does generate multiple errors actually.

When you are combining two scripts together, just add a prefix to each script's variables. It is always safer.

```
//@version=5
indicator(title="Donchian Channels", shorttitle="DC", overlay=true, timeframe="", timeframe_gaps=true)
dc_length = input.int(20, minval=1)
dc_lower = ta.lowest(dc_length)
dc_upper = ta.highest(dc_length)
dc_basis = math.avg(dc_upper, dc_lower)
plot(dc_basis, "Basis", color=#FF6D00)
dc_u = plot(dc_upper, "Upper", color=#2962FF)
dc_l = plot(dc_lower, "Lower", color=#2962FF)
fill(dc_u, dc_l, color=color.rgb(33, 150, 243, 95), title="Background")

///BB
bb_length = input.int(20, minval=1)
bb_src = input(close, title="Source")
bb_mult = input.float(2.0, minval=0.001, maxval=50, title="StdDev")
bb_basis = ta.sma(bb_src, bb_length)
bb_dev = bb_mult * ta.stdev(bb_src, bb_length)
bb_upper = bb_basis + bb_dev
bb_lower = bb_basis - bb_dev
bb_offset = input.int(0, "Offset", minval = -500, maxval = 500)
plot(bb_basis, "Basis", color=#FF6D00, offset = bb_offset)
bb_p1 = plot(bb_upper, "Upper", color=#2962FF, offset = bb_offset)
bb_p2 = plot(bb_lower, "Lower", color=#2962FF, offset = bb_offset)
fill(bb_p1, bb_p2, title = "Background", color=color.rgb(33, 150, 243, 95))
```

[image]